# Globals!ReportServerUrl Returning LocalHost Instead of Report Server URL

Tags: url, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, localhost, global

I am using a global variable in an SSRS but it is returning the wrong value.

`Globals!ReportServerURL` is supposed to return the actual report server URL, but instead it is returning "localhost" as the report server URL.

The `Globals!ReportServerURL` was returning the correct URL value on the test server, but as soon as I deployed it to the production server it started returning `http://localhost:8090/` instead.

Can someone give me direction on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance,

Marwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the following to the server configuration file:

```
<UrlRoot>
     http://ServerName/ReportServerName
</UrlRoot>
```